# Why won't Minecraft start?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

After I click on Minecraft the launcher comes up but when I press play the launcher goes away and my mouse makes a little swirly thing like its going to load but then it goes away.

I wait a while to try again but it's no different. I've tried taking my battery out but when I did it fixed something else I've been struggling with but not the Minecraft problem.

I've downloaded the same version over again nothing.

Extra Info

I'm on Windows, I've installed Forge, I have the Millienare mod & a bunch of maps.

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you running?

Comment: 1.7.2 @shanodin

Comment: I changed my profile from forge to my real one ant it worked but I want to play on forge

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure you have selected the Forge profile when playing:

[image: where to find profile choices]